# Print a character in the sql output

Tags: mysql

I am trying to print a $ sign before the amount. The output should look like

```
apple   $1.99
```

This the code I am using:

```
v.execute("SELECT  name,('$'+ CAST(Price AS VARCHAR(20))) FROM foods WHERE name =?",(n.get()))
```

I keep getting an error because of the $ sign.

Comment: MySQL != SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Comment: What error are you getting? And which database do yo use? MySql and Microsoft SQL Server are two different products.

Comment: Stating that you're using SQL is like saying you're speaking a Romance language. We still need to know whether it's French, Spanish, Italian...

Comment: I am using SQL, MySQL workbench, and python to connect to database

Comment: What is the full and complete text of the error message you get?

Answer (score 0):

How about `SELECT name,concat('$',CAST(Price AS VARCHAR(20))) FROM ...`

Comment: Should this be an answer to the given question? Then please add more details such that others can learn from it

Comment: Would you mind accept my answer? Thanks alot~ : ) @Legend7